# Angular 2 / 4 / 5 reactive forms validation - how to make it more concise?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

EDIT 2:

I have created an issue for the angular team to simplify the form validation. Give it thumbs up if you want a simpler form validation experience.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20477

EDIT 1:

The answer from H.abidi goes in the desired direction, but it only works for material components. In other words, I think the material also recognized this problem and they solved it for their components.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

This is an example of an input field without validation CSS styles or error messages (e.g. red border on input field when invalid):

```
    <input required type="date" id="Rechnungsdatum" name="Rechnungsdatum" formControlName="Rechnungsdatum">
    <label for="Rechnungsdatum">Rechnungsdatum*</label>
```

A similar input field with validation, where I apply CSS classes such as "valid valid--inline" or "invalid invalid-inline" via [ngClass] and where I display error messages and error icons looks like:

```
    <input required type="text" id="Rechnungsnummer" name="Rechnungsnummer" formControlName="Rechnungsnummer" [ngClass]="{'invalid invalid--inline': !signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').valid && (signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').touched || formDir.submitted),
    'valid valid--inline': signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').valid && (signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').touched || formDir.submitted)}">
    <label for="Rechnungsnummer">Rechnungsnummer*</label>
    <div class="message" *ngIf="!signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').valid && !signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').errors['required'] && (signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').touched || formDir.submitted)">
      <i class="icon icon-026-exclamation-mark-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Rechnungsnummer muss zwischen 3 und 6 Zeichen lang sein
    </div>
    <div class="message" *ngIf="signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').errors['required'] && (signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').touched || formDir.submitted)">
      <i class="icon icon-026-exclamation-mark-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Rechnungsnummer erforderlich
    </div>
```

The code:

```
!signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').valid && (signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').touched || formDir.submitted)
```

is repetitive. Is there a best practice to make this more concise? Or even to define some rules based on which CSS classes are added and error messages are displayed. I have a feeling that this is too much logic inside the template.

Additionally is it possible to avoid specifying the name of the form control for every input? E.g. instead of

```
signupForm.get('Rechnungsnummer').valid
```

have something like

```
signupForm.currentFormControl.valid
```

or like

```
<input id="1" #thisInput [ngClass]="{valid: thisInput.valid}>
<input id="2" #thisInput [ngClass]="{valid: thisInput.valid}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello With angular 5 you can use an ErrorStateMatcher.

Here's an example of use :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}

/** @title Input with a custom ErrorStateMatcher */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-error-state-matcher-example',
  templateUrl: './input-error-state-matcher-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-error-state-matcher-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorStateMatcherExample {
  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ]);

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
}
```

and in yur html you use something like this :

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl"
           [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I hope thois could help.

Comment: I think this only works with material components. The [errorStateMatcher] is only defined for material Input "matInput"  ( line 132 here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/33edff5f14394c740e7c5633bb2e7ba6505cff45/src/lib/input/input.ts). I am not using material components at the moment for inputs. I would prefer a generic solution.

Comment: As @Marcel states, this is not an Angular class. It belongs to Angular Material.

Answer (score 0):

Before using ErrorStateMatcher my code was like this :

```
    <p [class.errors]="form.controls.lastname.touched && form.controls.lastname.invalid">
      <mat-input-container>
        <input id="idLastname" matInput placeholder="Nom" formControlName="lastname">
        <span *ngIf="form.controls.lastname.touched && form.controls.lastname.errors?.required">
      <br>le nom est obligatoire</span>
      </mat-input-container>
    </p>
```

And css class errors

```
.errors {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try [ngxErrors](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ng-errors-form-validation)

```
<input type="text" formControlName="password">
  <div ngxErrors="password">
    <div ngxError="required" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
      Password is required
    </div>
    <div [ngxError]="['minlength', 'maxlength']" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
      5 characters minimum, 12 characters maximum
    </div>
  </div>
```